# Как реализовать модульность python скрипта?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как можно реализовать модульность python скрипта?

Нужно написать код который будет сканировать папку на наличие файлов .py и будет их "импортировать" в исполняемый скрипт. Проблема заключается в том, что количество этих файлов неизвесно и код менять нельзя. Я реализовывал через `exec()`, но это дико неудобно.

Comment: Можно через importlib это делать: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/a0b31824dd74d90842c243296afe9a4e22e39cf0/html_parsing/get_game_genres/common_utils.py#L21 А для рекурсивного обхода можно использовать `glob` с флагом `recursive` или `os.walk`

Comment: @gil9red я отстал от жизни, я даже не знал про этот респозиторий... Спасибо